# Image not visible during runtime

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to apply an image in the background of an html  tag through a CSS as below. Can any1 tell me why this image isnt  visible during runtime? I can see it during design time. Also, why do I have to give the full path?? Its not visible if I write only the image name.

```
.small-heading 
    {
   background:url(C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1 \WebApplication1\Images1\small-heading.gif);
   width: 105px;
    height: 20px;
  float: left;
 font-size: 0.9em;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #7a7a7a;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}
<strong class="small-heading">
 <a href="#" id="lnkPassword" >Change Password</a></strong>
 </td>
```

My image is in a folder called Image1 which is directly in the root. I have tried using this:

```
background:url(Images1\small-heading.gif);
```

It doesnt work...

Comment: <strong class="small-heading">
<a href="#" id="lnkPassword" >Change Password</a></strong>
</td>

Comment: try to create hiearchy and put your image folder in the root after that you can give a path images/small-heading.gif and obviosly it will work

Comment: Its already in the root.

Answer (score 3):

The url should always be relative to your web site or an http(s) address, not a local path.

Comment: so what do I put there? I am just working on an assignment. Its not a website that's gonna go live.

Comment: You could move the image in a subfolder of the html page and reference it using  background:url('images/Image.gif')

Comment: I have edited my original post. Did you get my point? It must be something with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the relative path.

Create an Image folder in you application root folder.
Place your Image there (as you all ready have Images1)
And use like this

```
background:url(Images1\small-heading.gif);
```

Take care of the file path. The css file where you have put the css-class should be at the root folder.
Other wise change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`background:url(Images1\small-heading.gif);`

use

`background:url('Images1/small-heading.gif');`

1. Your Image should be with .gif extension
2. place this code in a test.html file in and place it in a folder name `root`
3. inside `root` folder create a folder `Images1`
4. place `small-heading.gif` image inside this `Images1` folder.
5. open test.html by any browser and check.

**Full Code**

```
<html>
    <head>        
<style type="text/css">
.small-heading{
    background:url('Images1/small-heading.gif');
    width: 105px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}
.small-heading a{
    color:white;
    width: 105px;
    height: 20px;
    display:block;
}

</style>
    </head>
<body>
<strong class="small-heading">
<a href="#" id="lnkPassword" >Change Password</a>
</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing seems to be working... the image is displayed in the background only if I give the full local path, otherwise not. Even in that case it is not displayed when I run the application.

Answer (score 0):

try one thing- 
open that image in browser and copy the path from browser,not the whole path, if your image is in image folder take the path from that folder only and try that path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
background: url("Images1/small-heading.gif");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every1 for taking the trouble. This is what finally worked for me:

```
.small-heading 
{
background-image:url('../../Images1/small-heading.gif');
width: 105px;
height: 20px;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #7a7a7a;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}
```

However, if this (../../) works,  ~/Images1/....... should also work. Surprisingly, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "./Images/logo.jpg"  It will work fine